# Why does this proof fail?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm reading some notes on topology, and the notes' author is trying to raise motivation to consider compactness by providing a theorem whose proof is built intentionally wrong, but I don't agree with the reason he gives why the proof fails. Here's the theorem,

*Every sequence $0<a_n<1$ has a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ with $0<\lim a_{n_k}<1$*

and here's the (wrong) proof:

*Let's look at  a collection of intervals of the form $$(a_n- \frac{1}{2n} ,a_n+ \frac{1}{2n})$$ with n=1,2... Each of these intervals has length,  1/n, and since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1/n =\infty$ and the length of the interval (0,1) is 1, there must be a point l in (0,1) which is covered by infinite intervals, say $(a_{n_k}-\frac{1}{2n_k},a_{n_k}+\frac{1}{2{n_k}} )$*, therefore
$$\lim a_{n_k}=l\in(0,1)$$
The author says the proof is wrong because one can not always pick a finite subcover from an infinite cover (hence because the interval $(0,1)$ it's not compact), but I claim the proof breaks down even before that.

Why? Because there isn't always a point in $(0,1)$ which is covered by infinite intervals, and an example of a collection of intervals for which there isn't a point $l$ in $(0,1)$ which is covered by infinite intervals is obtained when we substitute $a_n$ for $\frac{1}{2n}$, that is, the collection $\{(0,1/n), n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

So my question is, where does the proof actually fail? And, if the author was right, could you give a better explanation than his?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: which textbook is this?

Comment: The implication here seems to be that we can only find a point contained in infinitely many elements of the open cover when the open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: Yes, your are right, but in that case, why can we only find a point contained in infinitely many elements of the open cover when the open cover has a finite subcover?. It's not a textbook, it was extracted from some notes on topology. By the way, the theorem itself is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by "the theorem itself is not true"?

Comment: I don't mean anything by that. It's just that someone asked me if the theorem was true or not, but in any case, I think it's irrelevant whether it is true or not

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "the theorem"?

Comment: Oh, never mind, you mean the statement at the beginning of your question.

Comment: Exactly. I know the theorem is not true beforehand, because the theorem's statement is only true for compact sets, and $(0,1)$ is not compact, so the proof must fail somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right about where the error is.  There are actually two different difficulties with concluding that there exists an $l\in(0,1)$ which is in infinitely many of the intervals $(a_n-1/2n,a_n+1/2n)$, though only one of them is fatal.  The first difficulty is that if $a_n$ is within $1/2n$ of $0$ or $1$, these intervals will not be entirely contained in $(0,1)$.  This, however, is easily remedied: just take *some* interval of length $1/n$ containing $a_n$ and contained in $(0,1)$ (though it may not be centered at $a_n$).

The second difficulty is, as you observe, that even though the total length of these intervals is infinite, there need not be any single point that is in infinitely many of them.  All you can conclude is that there is no uniform bound $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that every point of $(0,1)$ is in only $N$ of the intervals (because if there were, then the total length could be at most $N$).  But you might have points that are in arbitrarily large finite numbers of the intervals without having a point that is in infinitely many of them, and this is exactly what happens in your example.

It is entirely unclear what the author is trying to say; there is no obvious "open cover" here that you are taking a finite subcover of.  Moreover, this proof would *also* fail in $[0,1]$ (even though the conclusion is true in that case), because you can give the exact same counterexample to the argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand when you say that "then the total length could be at most N". Wouldn't the total length be $\sum_{i=1}^{N} 1/n $, which would never give a result of $N$? In any case, why, if there were a uniform bound $N$ such that every point is in only $N$ of the intervals, could then the total length be at most $N$?

Comment: If you have finitely many intervals in $(0,1)$ such that each point is contained in at most $N$ of the intervals, then their total length is at most $N$.  This is not too hard to prove by induction on the number of intervals (try proving it for $N=1$ to start; the general case is essentially the same because you can subdivide the intervals so that any two of them are either disjoint or equal).  The same statement follows for infinitely many intervals, because the "total length" (i.e., the infinite sum of their lengths) is defined as the supremum of the partial sums of finitely many of them.

Comment: In any case, I don't know where you're getting $\sum_{i=1}^N 1/n$ from.  There are still infinitely many intervals; it's just that any single point is only contained in at most $N$ of them (and not necessarily the first $N$ of them).  The intuition here is that if each point is in $N$ of the intervals, then when you add up their lengths you are getting the length of the entire interval $(0,1)$ multiplied by $N$ (since each point is getting counted $N$ times).  You can make this precise using measure theory machinery, or more directly and elementarily by the argument I suggested above.

Comment: You are right. I just thought that all the points could be contained in exactly the same first N intervals, but it doesn't have to be like that. As for the proof, I think it's a bit hard for me to construct it as I don't know much about Set Theory and Measure Theory, but after drawing several pictures now I get the idea why it is like you say, which disapproves what the author argues anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you.  The erroneous assumption  $E$ is just as you say : $\{(a_n-1/2n,a_n+1/2n)\} $ may be a  point-finite family in $(0,1)$. Of course if you discard the assumption $E$ but erroneously assume that $(0,1)$ is compact, you will deduce immediately the erroneous result that any convergent subsequence of $a_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to a point in $(0,1)$ because any metric on a compact metrizable space is a complete metric.